# no internet in terminal

Tags: linux, networking

I am using Linux system that comes with Windows 10 in developer mode.

The problem is that there is internet in `cmd` but there is no internet in the Linux terminal:

> [image]

system info:

Linux DESKTOP-9IC0VL5 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #836-Microsoft Mon May 05 16:04:00 PST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4275)?

Comment: thank you my friend
The problem has already been solved